# Network shuts down when downloading large file through 5 GHz network

Tags: networking, router

My router runs 2 networks. A 5 GHz network for newer devices, and a 2.4 GHz network for older devices. When I am downloading a large file and/or have a lot going on, if I am connected to the 5 GHz network, both networks disappear for about 10 seconds, then re-appear. I have a Linksys E3200 router.

This suddenly started happening about a month after we reset our router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues tend to be related to firmware or temperature, maybe both. Check you have the latest firmware, and use Google to see if anyone has any issues with the E3200 overheating. If you're running it in a warm, confined space, move it and see if problem goes away.

[Linksys E3200 Site with Firmware](http://www.linksys.com/gb/support-product?pid=01t80000003K7dcAAC)

Doesn't look like there's much in the way of updates. Check temperature then. Given the little you've posted, that's my best guess.

Comment: It seems like temperature was the issue. I did not know that downloading at 5.0 GHz made such a difference in heat than 2.4GHz

Comment: Good question. Why was the router reset in the first place? Can you confirm on another device that the networks actually disappear, or is there only the one?

Comment: Yes, the network goes away on every device in the house. And we reset the router because we changed our internet provider and the router would not stop complaining. We changed back to the previous provider, and the problem continued.